# Cannot find variable JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jframe, joptionpane

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int a=JoptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you really want to close the application","Select",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if(a==0)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Jridi Mohamed, please use the formatting tool to format your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a=JoptionPane.show..
```

Should be:

```
int a=JOptionPane.show..
```

Java is case sensitive, and the first 'o' of an option pane is a capital 'O'.